# v-autocomplete not option selected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, frontend, vuetify.js

I have one component in vue.js 2 and Vuetify that receive this data **:**

```
[ { "anio": 2022, "__typename": "Grupo" }, { "anio": 2020, "__typename": "Grupo" }, { "anio": 2018, "__typename": "Grupo" }, { "anio": 2017, "__typename": "Grupo" }, { "anio": 2016, "__typename": "Grupo" }, { "anio": 2015, "__typename": "Grupo" }, { "anio": 2014, "__typename": "Grupo" } ]
```

this `object array` it´s used in `:items` to `v-autocomplete` property.

```
<v-autocomplete
                    v-model="anyo"
                    :items="listAnyos"
```

But my problem is that I need option selected `v-model` that contains: `2023` but it never selected this option.

This data it´s getted from `graphql` and it´s sending to other component. All data it´s in `listAnyos` but i need to do, that if query graphql it´s empty set `anyo` or current year in `v-autocomplete`

**UPDATE**

with response i change my code to try it:

```
<v-autocomplete
                    label="Select Year"
                    :items="filteredYears"
                    item-text="anio"
                    item-value="anio"
                    v-model="selectedYear"
                    ></v-autocomplete>
```

and in methods:

```
calcularAnio() {
                let anioActual =  new Date().getFullYear();
                let previousYear = anioActual.value - 1;
                this.years.filter((year) => year.anio === anioActual.value || year.anio === previousYear.value)
            }
```

i created a function and change anonymous functions to values in variables and years in props. But not run, not show any errors but not run

**UPDATE 2**

in my parent component:

```
<BarraBusqueda
                    :listAnyos="listaAnyos"
                    :listNumLiquidaciones="listaNumLiquidaciones"
                    :cargandoAnyos="cargandoAnyos"
                    :cargandoRegistros="cargandoRegistros"
                    :filtros="filtros"
                    :fechaGas="fechaGas"
                    @buscar="leerRegistros"
                    v-if="fechaGas"
                />
```

this in my child component, when API responsed, return previous array. in my child component in function mounted i have this code:

const currYear = new Date().getFullYear();

```
if (!this.selectedYear) {
  this.listAnyos.unshift({
     "anio": currYear,
     "__typename": "Grupo"
  })

   this.items = this.listAnyos;
```

}

and my `v-autocomplete` now it´s:

```
<v-autocomplete
                    label="Ejercicio"
                    outline
                    v-model="selectedYear"
                    :items="items"
                    item-text="anio"
                    item-value="anio"
                    menu-props="offsetY"
                    :loading="cargandoAnyos"
                    :error-messages="anyoErrores"
                    :readonly="cargandoRegistros"
                />
```

But only can show current year, not all years. And current year it´s not selected

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: In your array no data related with 2023 is available.

Comment: so, there's no `2023` option in the data, and you want to select 2023?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes. If my query return null or empty i need that option selected it´s current year

Comment: @R.Mahbub yes, and i need that if my qury return null or empty set option autocomplete current year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to assign current year into the autocomplete and make that selected as a default if you are not getting a correct value of `selectedYear` from the backend or API call.

If Yes, Here is the working demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    listAnyos: [{
      "anio": 2022,
      "__typename": "Grupo"
    }, {
      "anio": 2020,
      "__typename": "Grupo"
    }, {
      "anio": 2018,
      "__typename": "Grupo"
    }, {
      "anio": 2017,
      "__typename": "Grupo"
    }, {
      "anio": 2016,
      "__typename": "Grupo"
    }, {
      "anio": 2015,
      "__typename": "Grupo"
    }, {
      "anio": 2014,
      "__typename": "Grupo"
    }],
    selectedYear: null,
  }),
  mounted() {
    const currYear = new Date().getFullYear(); 
    // Suppose you are getting value of anyo as null from the backend or API. Then you can just assign this 'currYear' to autocomplete and assign it as a selected value.
    if (!this.selectedYear) {
      this.listAnyos.unshift({
        "anio": currYear,
        "__typename": "Grupo"
      })
    }
    this.selectedYear = currYear
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-row
          align="center"
        >
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-autocomplete
              v-model="selectedYear"
              :items="listAnyos"
              item-text="anio"
              item-value="anio"
            ></v-autocomplete>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: @rohit-jidal if i want add current year to received data from my API and select this? because when static array object it´s all ok, but if i use response from my API disappear current year

Comment: Use separate variable for autocomplete `items`, Once you get the response from API, assign that into a separate variable and then add current year into that.

Comment: @rohit-jidal i´m sorry for my ignorance, but i don´t know very well how i can to do this. You can show my how could to be?

Comment: It will be difficult to explain without looking into your API response. But try in the way I suggested.

Comment: @rohit-jidal thanks for your time. I try your comment, but i can´t solve it... My API responsed ````listAnyos:```` i updated my question in update 2 with my actual code in my parent component and child component. Thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

```
import { computed } from "vue";

 const years = [
      { anio: 2022, __typename: "Grupo" },
      { anio: 2020, __typename: "Grupo" },
      { anio: 2018, __typename: "Grupo" },
      { anio: 2017, __typename: "Grupo" },
      { anio: 2016, __typename: "Grupo" },
      { anio: 2015, __typename: "Grupo" },
      { anio: 2014, __typename: "Grupo" },
    ];

    const currentYear = computed(() => new Date().getFullYear());
    const previousYear = computed(() => currentYear.value - 1);

    const filteredYears = computed(() =>
      years.filter((year) => year.anio === currentYear.value || year.anio === previousYear.value)
    );
```

```
   <div>
    <v-autocomplete
      label="Select Year"
      :items="filteredYears"
      item-text="anio"
      item-value="anio"
      v-model="selectedYear"
    ></v-autocomplete>
  </div>
```

Pls try it, hope it would work. Receive current year(2023) from Javascript.

Comment: @r-mahbub  this code it´s in computed or in other function?

Comment: Don't worry for computed. it is used for reactiveness and will automatically recalculate their values when any reactive data they depend on change.when the years array, currentYear, or previousYear change, the filteredYears computed property will automatically update its value.

Comment: @r-mahbub thanks for your help, but i don´t understand very well where should i put this code. i´m sorry i´m something newbie

Comment: @r-mahbub and selectedYear what it´s

Comment: @r-mahbub i think that your code it´s in vue js 3 and composition API. I´m using option API and VUEjs 2

Comment: There are no reactive dependencies in the `currentYear` and `previousYear` computeds. Why use a computed then? I don't think you should do that.

Comment: @moritz-ringler i think that this response it´s good, but i can´t try it because it think that it´s for vue 3 or composition API